# Apple application reject, notification problems on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, app-store-connect, uilocalnotification

I have an application in which user have to specify his telephone number and then application will send him an activation code for the application.

I've uploaded my build to itunes connect and have sent it on a beta test. Here is the message from Apple with my problem:

> 2.2 - Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected
>
> 2.2 Details
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8.3 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
>
> Specifically, we still are unable to receive a verification code.

I think that they've never received a notification on iPad. I've tested it on the emulator, because I haven't an actual device, and it works. I have only an iPhone 6, and there are no issues on it.

So, here is my code that sends a local notification:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // register for sending notifications
    let notificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    return true
}

var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
localNotification.alertAction = "Application activation code"
localNotification.alertBody = "Here is your activation code: " + "\(randomSerialNumber)"
localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1 )
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Is it possible to fix this problem? Or should I launch my application on real iPad device to clarify it?

Could this error occur because I use this code:

```
// register for sending notifications
let notificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: nil)
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

instead of this one:

```
// register for sending notifications
if application.respondsToSelector("isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications")
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    let notificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
} else {
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(.Badge | .Sound | .Alert)
}
```

Because I want my app to launch both on IOS 7 and 8 versions.

Comment: Is the verification code sent by sms or push notification? those mechanisms don't work on simulator

Comment: No, it's just a fake code in local notification. 

My customer said that he has no money for now to pay for sms verification and that's why verification code is send just in local notification.

Comment: Where do you call the bottom code?  Do you wait until the user has granted permission for notifications?  What if the user choses not to allow notifications?

Comment: The bottom code is called when user specified his telephone number and clicked the continue button. 

Permissions are asked immediately after application started. 

If notifications were not enabled by user then he will not be able to get the notification with activation code.

Comment: So it sounds like you need to either, not enable the continue button until you receive confirmation from the OS that notifications are permitted and/or inform the user that they cannot continue until they permit notifications in settings (assuming they have declined to receive notifications)

Comment: But why it works on iPhone and don't on iPad?